# When creating TextView dynamically the second TextView is not appearing

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, layoutparams

I'm creating two TextViews in my LinearLayout using the code below. I'm using them this way to catch a touch event when the press this specified area of the screen

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    LinearLayout layOut = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.loginView);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams loginParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(520, 70);
    loginParams.setMargins(120, 670, 0, 0);
    TextView loginBttn = new TextView(this);
    layOut.addView(loginBttn);
    loginBttn.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    loginBttn.setLayoutParams(loginParams);
    loginBttn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // Code touch events
        }
    });

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams forgotParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(370, 40);
    forgotParams.setMargins(150, 770, 0, 0);
    TextView forgotBttn = new TextView(this);
    layOut.addView(forgotBttn);
    forgotBttn.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);        
    forgotBttn.setLayoutParams(forgotParams);
    forgotBttn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // Code touch events
        }
    });
```

I'm using Green to locate them. When finished I'll take those lines out. The first works and appears fine but the second does not appear and I can't see why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its out of screen try lower values for margin and position
eg:

```
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams loginParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(50, 50);
    loginParams.setMargins(10, 10, 0, 0);
    TextView loginBttn = new TextView(this);
    layOut.addView(loginBttn);
    loginBttn.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    loginBttn.setLayoutParams(loginParams);


    LinearLayout.LayoutParams forgotParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(10, 10);
    forgotParams.setMargins(20, 20, 0, 0);
    TextView forgotBttn = new TextView(this);
    layOut.addView(forgotBttn);
    forgotBttn.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);        
    forgotBttn.setLayoutParams(forgotParams);
```

Comment: That worked, I forgot Linear lays one after another, thank you